# text-overflow: ellipsis problems in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, ellipsis

I'm trying to shorten the length of columns in a certain table.

I'm using some jQuery to add text-overflow ellipsis and a few more css properties.
 I also add a tooltip using some more jQuery.
Here's my code:

```
$('#table_id tr td:not(:last)').css({
"text-overflow": "ellipsis",
"max-width": "110px",
"overflow": "hidden",
"display" : "block"
}).each(function (index, element) { $(element).attr("title", $(element).text()); });
```

Everything works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but (surprise! surprise!) IE7-9 renders the text in it's full length.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

P.S.
I've also tried specifying the "width" property with no avail.

Comment: try adding `white-space: nowrap` and `width:100%`.

Answer (score 6):

You need `white-space:nowrap;` on the `td` as well. Additionally, `table-layout:fixed;` must be set on the table itself, or IE still won't cut off the text.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that runs across this problem, I found that I had to define a height to make IE happy, `height:20px;`

Answer (score 0):

IE7 won't apply text-overflow on table elements — you'll have to wrap the contents in an otherwise superfluous containing element, and apply your `text-overflow` (and associated styles) to that:

```
$('#table_id tr td:not(:last)').each(function (index, element) {
  var $el  = $(element);
  var text = $el.text();
  var html = $el.html();

  $el.attr("title", text).empty();

  $('<div>').css({
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
    "max-width"    : "110px",
    "overflow"     : "hidden",
    "display"      : "block"
  }).html(html).appendTo($el);
}
```